# Barplot with qualitative variables multi-select R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, charts

I am very new to Shiny and R and reactivity and could really use an assist. I have a dataset ("transport") that has columns "midwest", "northeast", "europe" and then rows "cars", "busses", "trains" with numbers as the data. (ie: midwest & cars = 10.)

I'd like to use selectizeInput or another input format that allows for multiple criteria to be selected. The criteria should be the columns ("midwest", "northeast", "europe").

The Y axis of the bar plot should be the rows from the dataset ("cars", "busses", "trains") and the bars should be the input ("midwest", "northeast", "europe"). If multiple regions are selected, multiple bars would appear for each category on the x axis. If one region is selected, one bar appears for each of the rows.

I'm sure this seems easy to many experienced Shiny users out there, but I feel like I've tried a million different tutorials and just can't get it right! Thank you very much for your help.

I can get a regular bar plot with numeric values and just selectInput, but I can't get the categorical or multiple values to work for the life of me. Gah!!!!!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided simple [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what you have so far. You're more likely to get someone to assist once you've provided some code.

Comment: From the descirption of your data I would guess that you have to reshape your data such that you end up with three columns, i.e. type of transport, region, value.